# passing arbitrary (unused) keyword arguments to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a small plotting function that uses matplotlib, and then makes some tweaks based on user input provided in **kwargs.

This does not work the way I expected because if the keyword argument is not known in matplotlib (looks like within artist.py), then I get an exception.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def invalid_mpl(**kwargs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,3], [-3, -2, -1], **kwargs)
    return fig, ax
```

This works fine if called like

```
f0, a0 = invalid_mpl()
```

or with a valid kwarg like

```
f0, a0 = invalid_mpl(color='red')
```

but raises `AttributeError: Unknown property my_fake_kwarg` for

```
f0, a0 = invalid_mpl(my_fake_kwarg=True)
```

So I guess my questions are:
1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. Is there a way to parse the kwargs for valid matplotlib keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. matplotlib won't accept unknown keyword arguments. Making `my_fake_kwarg` an explicit keyword argument won't fix things. With

```
def valid_mpl(my_fake_kwarg=None, **kwargs):
    do_something_with(my_fake_kwarg)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,3], [-3, -2, -1], **kwargs)
    return fig, ax
```

`valid_mpl(my_fake_kwarg=True)` still results in `kwargs = {'my_fake_kwarg': True}`.

You could remove it from `kwargs` after you're done with it.

```
def valid_mpl(**kwargs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    if 'my_fake_kwarg' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['my_fake_kwarg']

    ax.plot([1,2,3], [-3, -2, -1], **kwargs)
    return fig, ax
```

Or create a new dictionary to unpack into `ax.plot`.

```
def valid_mpl(**kwargs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    fake_kwargs = ['my_fake_kwarg']
    plot_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k not in fake_kwargs}

    ax.plot([1,2,3], [-3, -2, -1], **plot_kwargs)
    return fig, ax
```

Comment: Just FWIW, the way I got around this issue was to use use the pop operation on kwargs to remove any non matplotlib options before passing the remainder on to the plotting part. This seems conceptually similar to your suggestions.